# How to get a list of tuples with some value based on its minimum value - Only with native libraries from Python

Tags: python, list, append, list-comprehension, min

I have the following code... But I need to get the corresponding filename for the minimum value:

```
import itertools

arrayFiles = []
for subset in itertools.combinations(distances, 2):
  array = []
  for k in range(K):
    array.append(min([(n[1][k]) for n in subset]))
  arrayFiles.append(array)
```

For instance, I have the following sample data `K = 10` and distances list is:

```
distances = [('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]),
             ('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993]),
             ('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]),
             ('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]),
             ('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]),
             ('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]),
             ('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005]),
             ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001]),
             ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482]),
             ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])]
```

|  | highway_bost174 | ibis_142 | street_par88 | opencountry_241 | waterfall23 | field26 | mountain_030 | horse_081 | bison_052 | ibis_040 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| highway_bost174 | 0 | 8.708170812 | 4.088197921 | 11.366319880 | 12.63876329 | 11.07823394 | 10.02510284 | 8.415467337 | 8.194840093 | 13.45505618 |
| ibis_142 | 8.708170812 | 0 | 10.518235207 | 7.668395996 | 10.5223999 | 7.302185059 | 6.417022705 | 6.146172005 | 10.44835499 | 5.149291993 |
| street_par88 | 4.088197921 | 10.51823521 | 0. | 11.135904053 | 11.47283127 | 10.69156812 | 9.663827636 | 10.65966088 | 9.392413014 | 12.5860189 |
| opencountry_241 | 11.36631988 | 7.668395996 | 11.135904053 | 0. | 13.31494141 | 2.754882813 | 3.998626709 | 9.028326501 | 12.14570309 | 8.675354003 |
| waterfall23 | 12.63876329 | 10.5223999 | 11.472831274 | 13.314941407 | 0 | 12.66552734 | 11.40634155 | 12.6048929 | 11.43774673 | 8.79888916 |
| field26 | 11.07823394 | 7.302185059 | 10.691568116 | 2.754882813 | 12.66552734 | 0 | 3.349212646 | 8.966176812 | 11.82766924 | 8.203674316 |
| mountain_030 | 10.02510284 | 6.417022705 | 9.663827636 | 3.998626709 | 11.40634155 | 3.349212646 | 0 | 8.78585096 | 11.99428394 | 7.732574462 |
| horse_081 | 8.415467337 | 6.146172005 | 10.65966088 | 9.028326501 | 12.6048929 | 8.966176812 | 8.78585096 | 0 | 8.054160894 | 11.09364108 |
| bison_052 | 8.194840093 | 10.44835499 | 9.392413014 | 12.145703089 | 11.43774673 | 11.82766924 | 11.99428394 | 8.054160894 | 0 | 12.86955948 |
| ibis_040 | 13.45505618 | 5.149291993 | 12.586018896 | 8.675354003 | 8.79888916 | 8.203674316 | 7.732574462 | 11.09364108 | 12.86955948 | 0 |

What I need is to get a list of tuples such as the one down bellow where the string which comes before the name is the corresponding result of the first element of each tuple of the list distances... That's it the correposding name of the min value...

The way you can see in the table down bellow:

[image]

**OUTPUT**

```
  [[("highway_bost174", 0), ("ibis_142",0),("highway_bost174", 4.088197921),("ibis_142", 7.668395996),("ibis_142", 10.5223999), ("ibis_142", 7.302185059), ( "ibis_142", 6.417022705), ("ibis_142", 6.146172005),("highway_bost174", 8.194840093),("ibis_142", 5.149291993)]...]
```

**Please send me only stuff based on native libraries from Python**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools
arrayFiles = []
for subset in itertools.combinations(distances, 2):
    one = subset[0]
    two = subset[1]
    one_tup = [(subset[0][0], x) for x in subset[0][1]]
    two_tup = [(subset[1][0], x) for x in subset[1][1]]
    pair = [(o, two_tup[i]) for (i, o) in enumerate(one_tup)]
    res_list = []
    for e in pair:
        if e[1][1] > e[0][1]:
            res_list.append(e[0])
        else:
            res_list.append(e[1])
    arrayFiles.append(res_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for repliyng me, however that is not quite what I am looking for...
Please take a look at the output I furnished you with
' [[("highway_bost174", 0), ("ibis_142",0),("highway_bost174", 4.088197921),("ibis_142", 7.668395996),("ibis_142", 10.5223999), ("ibis_142", 7.302185059), ( "ibis_142", 6.417022705), ("ibis_142", 6.146172005),("highway_bost174", 8.194840093),("ibis_142", 5.149291993)]...]'

Comment: Ok, so you would like a list of tuples (<name>, <distance>) sorted by the lowest distance? Am I missing something, because that is what I think I have done.

Comment: Yes, take a look at the second table... The names there correspond to each of its correponding files... at column initial choice

Comment: May I suggest running the following: `dist2 = distances[0:2]` followed by `sorted([(d[0], x) for d in dist2 for x in d[1]], key=lambda k: k[1])`. I think this provides the output you were after.

Comment: Do you want this list for every combination of destinations in `distances`?

Comment: Yes, That`s what I need

Comment: I've just edited my answer with this - it now provides a list of lists of every combination of two destinations in the `distances` list.

Comment: Ok... that's quite better, however I do not want the lists of tuples to be ordered... Only the minimum values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231630/discussion-between-tytrox-and-lucasbbs).